# Percentage formatting not copied to new rows in excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

Whenever I create a table in excel with a column with percentage formatting, the formatting never is copied to any new rows created by dragging down the bottom right corner of the table to add new rows.

I have 2 columns in a table I currently am working with. One, is `=[Currency]/Constant` Where both referenced cells are currencies. The second column is `=[Currency]/([DateTime]-Constant)` where [Currency] is a currency cell, and [DateTime] and Constant are both datetimes.

When I add a new row by dragging the bottom right corner, I get a currency cell and a date time cell, rather than a percentage with 2 decimal places as is in every cell above in the same column.

[image]

This isn't just happening in this instance, I regularly get this problem with percentages, just not with any other format.

EDIT:

This isn't the same as the normal formatting of the table, such as the colour of cells, etc. It is specifically, only happening with cells meant to show a percentage. They are changing their data type to another. To replicate:

- Enter "Col A" into B2
- Enter "Col B" into C2
- Enter "20" into A1
- Enter "10" into B3
- Enter "=B3/A$1" into C3
- Format A1 as a currency data type
- Format C3 as a percentage
- Select B2:C3, and press CTRL+T. Make the range a table, with headers in the dialog.
- Now grab the table grab handle (as seen in image above) to pull the table down a row to get a new row in the table.

The new row will have a currency format in column C. Now try anything you like to have it remain as a percentage and add naother new row - notice that it always reverts back to currency.

EDIT 2:
Added a video showing me doing this, and attempting to remedy it with proposed solutions. This is in a fresh workbook. https://youtu.be/NslCFW2mMrc

Comment: After you drag to create new cells, you can change how Excel formats those new cells with the little icon that pops up on the bottom right. I think the defaults are "Copy cells, Fill Formatting Only, Fill Without Formatting". Looks like it's defaulting to Fill without Formatting, but you can click "Fill Formatting Only". Does that do the trick?

Comment: Nothing like you mentioned pops up when increasing the size of the table using the grab handle at bottom right of the table.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Edit - [uploaded a picture](https://i.imgur.com/9Zq0uLo.png) of the popup that appears after using the fill series dragging handle.

Comment: That is not a table. I am talking about a table you have created in Excel, where you are adding a new row by grabbing the handle shown in the image I posted at bottom right. No cells in the table need to be selected to do it, unlike the fill series you are showing.

Comment: Oh, duh...missed that part. Sounds like this might be a dupe of [Excel table not formatting new rows appropriately - where does the formatting come from?](https://superuser.com/questions/885587/excel-table-not-formatting-new-rows-appropriately-where-does-formatting-come-f?rq=1). Have you tried right clicking on the column header and then selecting "Format Cells"?

Comment: I didnt know about that right click format on table header, but this still didnt work with the percentage formatting. Tried each answer on the linked page, nothing seemed to remedy this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel table not formatting new rows appropriately - where does formatting come from?](https://superuser.com/questions/885587/excel-table-not-formatting-new-rows-appropriately-where-does-formatting-come-f)

Comment: AS stated already - it is not a dupe of that. I have added repro steps to my OP.

Comment: I followed the steps you outlined in your edit...and I hate to say this, [but it works fine for me](https://i.imgur.com/C5u4hbV.png). Even if I formatted C5 as currency before dragging down the table, it still converted to a percentage. The format of a cell in a formula (A1 in this case) should not affect the format of the destination cell. Do you have any conditional formatting rules running that might be causing the problem? Hard to diagnose with the small snip of your table.

Comment: I have tried the exact steps on a fresh sheet, and get this problem both at home and at work. No conditional formatting, and it happens on a fresh sheet for me also.

Comment: Argh. We're going to get this! What version of Excel are you using? For Mac or PC? Also, does the same thing happen if you right click and "add row below" or "insert row" from the table options in the ribbon?

Comment: It does happen if right clicking and hitting add row below also. I uploaded a video showing me doing this, here: https://youtu.be/NslCFW2mMrc And my version is Excel 2016, specifically: 16.0.8431.2110

Comment: @pingu2k4 I _might_ have just figured out how to recreate the problem. I went into Options from the File menu, then to the Formulas section and changed [Workbook Calculation to "Automatic except for data tables"](https://i.imgur.com/o6w2Pl5.png). When Workbook Calculation was set to Automatic (default in my case), it worked fine. Changing it changed the new cell to "Accounting" from Percentage. Can you check your Formula Calculation options?

Comment: My calculation defaults to automatic, have never changed it in anything I use :( The vid posted was a fresh workbook, so was automatic also. :(

Comment: I hate to say it, but I might be stumped. Any luck in the past couple days?

Comment: I'm fresh out of ideas, sorry. Thanks for the help though! :)